# Delphi и Visual Studio

Tags: delphi, visual-studio, ide

Доброго времени суток! По учебе дали задание - описать достоинства и недостатки среды delphi 7 по сравнению с visual studio 12. Помогите.

Comment: там русским по белому написано - задали по учебе

Comment: teanЫЧ прав глупо сравнивать... , да и более того чтобы реально сравнить нужно долго пользоваться обоими средами... лично я (на данный момент) пользовался только VS10 и Bulder6  в первом с++ + консоль, и немного web во втором с++ + gui. в vs понравился текстовый редактор его возможности по "заточки под себя" билдер сильно уступает... также понравилось сохранение файла(Ctrl+s) в vs в файле изменяется только та строка  которая  была изменена а в билдере файл полностью перезаписывается...  за счёт этого vs сохраняет в несколько раз быстрее...   Остальное не мне судить  так как только учусь ...

Comment: Да, сравнение, конечно, не в пользу дельфи, да и весьма странное - это как теплое и мягкое сравнивать. С другой стороны, и то, и то - RAD'ы, так что вполне можно попробовать. Для начала нужно выделить критерии сравнения. И после этого погнали содержательную часть. Начать можно хотя бы с отличия языков и расширяемости сред другими языковыми инструментами

Comment: Мда ,месье знает толк в извращениях - все же delphi 7 вышла в 2002 году, если не ошибаюсь, а VS 2012 - сами понимаете в каком. 
И выводы тут напрашиваются следующие: 
1. Препод, задавший это, явно садомазохист с некрофильскими наклонностями - чтобы измываться так над трупом 7-ой  delphi, надо иметь нездоровую психику.
2. Пугает уровень нашего образования - уж если у нас во многих вузах программистов до сих пор учат насквозь прогнившим технологиям и языкам, покрывшимся заслуженной плесенью, то это явно говорит не в пользу нашей системы образования.

Comment: @DreamChild, ничего не имею против изучения pascal/delphi на первых стадиях обучения. Меня больше удивила сама задача.

Comment: @DreamChild, ИМХО,с 2-м пунктом не согласен. Есть и люди пишущие на асм, фортран. Смотря с каким инструментом кто как пользоваться умеет.Технология то наверное несильная по сравнению с VS 2012, но не заслуженная точно плесенью.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, я тоже ничего не имею против, сам начинал с pascal, меня точно так же, как и вас удивил вопрос

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, вы меня неправильно поняли. Я так сказал не потому, что имею что-то против delphi, а потому что считаю, что нужно пользоваться современными инструментами, а delphi 7 таковым инструментом не является. Это касается как версии языка, так и IDE

Comment: @DreamChild, язык одинаковый, что в 7'ке, что в RAD'e. Отсюда следует, что нет никакой разницы в какой IDE учить <strike>ребенка грамоте</strike> будущего программиста мыслить логически, и работать с графическим интерфейсом. А использование Delphi 7 логично для этой страны, ибо её проще достать и крякнуть. А если на среду возлагается минимальная задача, то зачем <strike> стрелять из пушки по муравьям</strike> ставить навороченную XE2? Может вы еще против изучение pascal и C на первых курсах в вузах/технарях?

Comment: @DreamChild, язык одинаковый, что в 7'ке, что в RAD'e. Отсюда следует, что нет никакой разницы в какой IDE учить будущего программиста мыслить логически, и работать с графическим интерфейсом. А использование Delphi 7 логично для этой страны, ибо её проще достать и крякнуть. А если на среду возлагается минимальная задача, то зачем ставить навороченную XE2? Может вы еще против изучение pascal и C на первых курсах в вузах/технарях? Или вы за изучение "Выжрал Васика"? Или сразу взрывать мозги плюсами?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, читайте внимательнее, и не ищите в моих словах того, что я не говорил.  я еще раз специально для вас повторю - я не против изучения паскаля как учебного языка (хотя, java или c# были бы лучше). Я не за изучение Васика. 
И пару слов по сабжу. Если вы считаете, что delphi 7 мало отличается от последних версий, то посмотрите список нововведений в языке за последние 10 лет, он вас удивит. Возможности IDE  также шагнули очень далеко, и не пользоваться ими тоже не совсем правильно. Пользоваться ими стоит даже в учебных целях - более удобный инструмент никому еще не мешал

Comment: Скажите преподу что он идиот и забирайте документы из вуза, там вас точно ничему не научат, бегите от туда пока не поздно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если уж так преподаватель поставил вопрос, то скорее всего он просто не любит делфи, либо не знает (не хочет знать) о новых версиях. Но если бы это был мой билет и так поставлен вопрос, то отвечал бы где то так.

Делфи7, плюсы:

- работает на реально древних машинах (я лично запускал на первом пентиуме, 166МГц + 48ОЗУ, и мелкие проги можно делать и компилить).
- занимает немного места (вроде мегабайт 200-300 на диске).
- не требует .NET.
- работает на Windows 2000 и старше.
- список багов давно известный. Система предсказуемая.
- в большинстве случаев не нужно никаких дополнительных длл/манифестов.
- можно  не инсталлировать, а просто распаковать с архива и чуточку поднастроить и можно  работать.

минусы:

- вопросы по ней на форумах нужно задавать аккуратно - могут зафлеймить и обозвать некрофилом.
- BDE (но многим нравится)
- большой размер exe (да, пару сотен килобайт).
- нельзя писать на с++ (табличка сарказм, подымаемая с задних парт).

VS2012, плюсы:

- новомодная система. на форумах выглядишь крутом(табличка сарказм).
- навороченный дизайн, вызывающий восторг блондинок (капс в меню).
- тонны примочек, одни названия которых вызывают экстаз.
- можно писать на куче языков. Чего только стоит с++ в двух модификациях.
- поддержка последнего стандарта с++0х
- поддержка 8 винды с метро стилем.

минусы:

- только одна инсталляция на пару гигабайт.
- после инсталляции обнаруживается куча мусора, начиная с эмуляторов устройств и заканчивая серверами, которые так и хотят процессорного времени.
- в очередной раз переработанный интерфейс.
- новые, неизведанные баги.
- не поддерживает делфи (правда есть Delphi Prism, который работает как плагин, но есть ли он под 2012?).

Признаком удачного ответа будет дружный хохот с задних парт и вызов к декану по причине издевательства с преподавателя.

Comment: Извините, но  зачем Delphi C++? Для C++ есть Borland C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1):

С Visual Studio может соперничать разве что с RAD Studio. Обе - современные продукты, много чего поддерживают. По языкам C++ и еще...  По платформам: windows и другие. Это современные продукты. А Дельфи (Запорожец) - да не прихотлив, да ездит, но это вчера было хорошо и всех устраивало. Удачи в написании.

Answer (score 0):

Специально для вас.

[Delphi wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8))
[Visual studio wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio)

Delphi 7 [сайт продавца с описанием](http://softour.ru/ru/programming/sreda-razrabotki/92-borlanddelphi7.html)
[Мелкомягкие о VS12](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/rus/visual-studio-update#story-update-1)

ну и дальше в том же духе

Answer (score 0):

Ребята правильно в каментах написали, что только идиот может сравнивать 2 совершенно разных IDE, выпущенные в совершенно разные времена.

Delphi 7 выпущена в 2002 году, VS 2012 - в 2012 году. Отличий - 100500 миллиардов. Первое из них - язык разработки. Это разные, так сказать, платформы, их некорректно сравнивать.

Но если вам это обязательно необходимо сделать, просто почитайте вики про делфи, и технологии делфячьи, и про визуал-студио.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi:
Плюсы:

- очень большой выбор компонентов для програмирования.
- програмировать надо на Pascal (Object) (pascal легкий для обучения)
- компилятор достаточно хорош.
- большой выбор API фунций.
- трасировка программы
- большой Help
  Минусы:
- полная версия занимет много места (у меня 500 Мб)
- слабая поддержка железа (про Android даже и не мечтайте)

---

Я рекомедую Java. Она поддерживает очень много систем и железа.

Comment: Добавлю: не поддерживает Юникода(Дельфи) ,вплот до 2009 или 2010 версий, точно не помню, но 7 ка точно не поддерживает.

Comment: @MrGons18 много систем и железа? да конечно:)

Comment: > очень большой выбор компонентов для програмирования.

речь про VCL или сторонние библиотеки?

> програмировать надо на Pascal (Object) (pascal легкий для обучения)

это не плюс, а особенность. Сам по себе ObjectPascal, наверное, не лучший ооп язык.

> компилятор достаточно хорош.

говно. К тому же есть альтернативы - FPC, например. Только вот как его прикрутить к дельфям?

> большой выбор API фунций.

???

> большой Help

а MSDN еще больше.

> полная версия занимет много места (у меня 500 Мб)

какой-нить $*#^$*@ Platform SDK из студии метров 300 может занять. И это без toolchain'а.